# Как получить массив char, зная указатель на него

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, char

Функция  `CpyWithoutPoints` возвращает указатель на массив `char` (строку), не могу понять, как получить саму строку.

```
char tempName[30];

*tempName = CpyWithoutPoints(&str[0]);           
printf("%s ", tempName); - выводит какой то мусор и в конце нужную строку
```

Comment: Попробуйте объявить так: char* tempName;

Comment: Если Вы хотите получить в этот массиве `tempName[]` копию данных, указатель на которые возвращает `CpyWithoutPoints()`, то просто скопируйте их в массив -- `strcpy(tempName, CpyWithoutPoints(&str[0]));` / Сам же заголовок вопроса просто ужасен, похоже свидетельствует о полном непонимании сути массивов и указателей. Очевидно из-за проблем с базовыми знаниями об устройстве компьютера.

Answer (score 2):

В C, строка есть не что иное, как указатель на свой первый элемент. Конструкция наподобие `char tempName[30];` объявляет массив символов, который совместим с указателем на стартовый символ, и поэтому может рассматриваться как строка.

Кроме того, строки не копируются так просто, при помощи `=` копируются лишь сами указатели, но не содержимое строки.

Для того, чтобы скопировать содержимое, нужно воспользоваться функциями наподобие `strcpy`. Но в вашем примере это не нужно, ведь у вас и так есть строка!

Попробуйте избавиться от выделения массива `tempName`.

```
char* tempName = CpyWithoutPoints(&str[0]);           
printf("%s ", tempName);
```